# Game development

Tags: android, разработка-игр

Здравствуйте. Можете, пожалуйста, подсказать какую-то бесплатную литературу, онлайн уроки, или что-то подобное для ознакомления с темой: "Разработка игр под Android". С чего стоит начинать и куда двигаться дальше?

Comment: Начать стоит с поиска и двигаться по ссылкам в нем ;)

Comment: @andreyqin, найти можно много чего. Но мне интересно мнение людей, которые имеют опыт в разработке игр. Например, как вы относитесь к libGDX? Или вы можете посоветовать какую-то другую библиотеку для разработки игр? Если да, то почему?

Comment: Как раз такие вещи и ищутся в поиске. Или вы думаете, что "где-то там" люди отвечают на подобные вопросы без опыта? Я, например, не пишу ничего конкретного вам, потому что "не в теме", зато если вдруг приспичит, на пару часов изучу тему и подберу необходимую литературу и курсы.

Comment: UNITY 3d for all

Comment: DDMetaPlayer

Comment: Я думаю, что [вот этот ресурс](http://startandroid.ru/ru/uroki/vse-uroki-spiskom) будет не совсем лишним для автора вопроса.

Comment: а причем тут gamedev?

Comment: @gcoder, как не странно, у StartAndroid есть курсы по gamedev (по крайне мере, видел на YouTube'е) с использованием libGDX.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Есть книга Марио Цехнера "Программирование игр под Андроид" ([скачать](http://ad-file.com/59625008)).
Вот еще пару ссылок, по которым я учусь:
[1 тык](http://davidmd.ru/уроки-по-android/);
[2 тык](http://redgears.ru/основы-работы-с-графикой-android-часть-2/);
[3 тык](http://megadarja.blogspot.com/2009/03/android-1-surface.html);
[4 тык](http://dajver.blogspot.com/2012/01/android-5-2d.html);
[5 тык](http://dedfox.com/izuchaem-opengl-es2-pod-android-urok-1-samoe-nachalo/);

Comment: Отлично, благодарю!

Comment: Незачто! Кстати Марио Цехнер - создатель движка libGDX

Comment: @SlowAR, занятно. Как раз будет, чем заняться, по окончанию сессии. :)

Answer (score 7):

Как уже тут говорили, стоит понять свой уровень, а уже потом двигаться дальше.

Если же давать советы:

1. Я бы посоветовал чистый OpenGL поизучать, чтобы понять конвейр работы GPU и т.п.
2. Потом выбрать движок.

   2.1. Если хотим проф. качать скил, то надо что-то вроде Unreal Engine (благо сейчас можно билдить и мобильные версии + лицензия не кусается больше).

   2.2 Если преимущественно на мобилки, то Unity3d можно.
3. От себя бы посоветовал LibGDX. Сам по этому движку писал [статьи](http://suvitruf.ru/libgdx/). Делал игры: [Bomberman](http://suvitruf.ru/bomberman-na-android/), [Lode Runner](http://lode-runner.suvitruf.ru/). Даже выкладывал [исходники](https://github.com/Suvitruf/libgdx/tree/master/NES%20Bomberman) бомбермена. Для ознакомления вам это, я думаю, хватит (:

Comment: Попадал на ваши статьи. Спасибо. Думаю, пока достаточно. Буду отталкиваться от этой информации.

Comment: Unreal Engine не очень подходит в данном случае. Мобильные платформы он начал поддерживать не так давно, а значит, под Android там вряд ли много написано. Unity3D подходит для этого куда лучше, там и условия лицензии хорошие, можно бесплатно выпустить (кроме $25 на Google Play за аккаунт разработчика). LibGDX хорошая вещь, гибкая, высокопроизводительная, тоже хороший вариант. Самый простой вариант: изучить Unity3D и всё. Но мне этот вариант не нравиться, так как нет полного понимания процесса. Хоть и учится очень быстро! А вот если писать на LibGDX, то OpenGL тут, можно сказать, обязателен!

Comment: @SemperPeritus 1.5к $ на лицензию для Юнити не все могут себе позволить

Comment: Можно использовать не Pro, а обычную версию, только там чуть меньше возможностей (в основном графических, таких как реалистичная вода, или продвинутый тип освещения, редактор кода и другие...) и появляется логотип Unity при запуске, если прибыль не превышает $100 000. Точные условия сейчас назвать не могу, кому интересно могут прочитать на официальном сайте (сравнение в графическом виде, или просто - таблица) http://unity3d.com/unity/licenses